# Javascript hover function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, raphael

i am trying out raphael with javascript and trying to get the hang of it. At the moment i am trying to get it so that when the user hovers over a circle in raphael which i have drawn it will create a simmple hover messge like hi. However i am stuck to an end on this part, i cant seem to do anything about, any help on this would be great.

Javascript:

```
window.onload= function (){ 
    var paper = new Raphael( 0, 0, 400, 400);
    var backGround = paper.rect(0, 0, 400, 400);
    backGround.attr({ fill: "orange"});
    var face = paper.circle(200,200,100);
    face.attr({ fill: "Red"});
};
```

HTML

```
<div class= "bot">
    <p>Hi there</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `Element.hover()` function, as documented on the [Raphael website](http://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/reference.html#Element.hover).

**Update**: *The code snippet posted below works if you copy it onto your own computer and run it locally. However, to actually run this snippet on Stack Overflow, it only works on some browsers (e.g. it works on Firefox, but not on Chrome), probably due to the different browsers allowing or not allowing the code snippets to load external libraries, like Raphael.js, as required in this code snippet.*

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var paper = new Raphael(0, 0, 400, 400);

  var backGround = paper.rect(0, 0, 400, 400);

  backGround.attr({
    fill: "orange"
  });

  var face = paper.circle(200, 200, 100);

  face.attr({
    fill: "Red"
  });
  
  face.hover(hoverHandler);

};

function hoverHandler() {
  alert("hi");
}
```

```html
<script src="http://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/raw/master/raphael-min.js"></script>
<div class="bot">
  <p>Hi there</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to get it so that, its just like a small box when u hver over it> Not like this big one?

Comment: Are you perhaps asking how to change from causing an alert to appear to causing a smaller normal HTML element (e.g. a small div) to appear?